# How to extract contours from a grainy image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

How do I extract contour lines and successive distances between them when the image is grainy.

I have an image like this,

[image]

I would like to draw a rough circle around the clusters of points with the most number of similar colored pixels and calculate the width of the ring formed. For example,

[image]

Only to calculate the length of the black arrows.

So far, I have tried opencv's `findContours()` method, but it just draws around the whole image itself, probably because this image is a bit too grainy.

Comment: why is this colored like that? why is it binary at all? why are those blocks of different sizes? are those screenshots?